# installing window service using command prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-services, windows-7-x64

I tried to install my simple window service developed by VS 2012 on Windows 7 64 bit.

For its installation, I follow [this Blog](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/06/how-to-install-windows-service-using.html)

But i got this "InstallUtil.InstallLog" file -

> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of
>   the log file for the e:\ABC\WindowService_VS2012\wins_Test.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   e:\ABC\WindowService_VS2012\wins_Test.InstallLog.
>
> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
>   System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some
>   or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
>
> The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning. See the contents
>   of the log file for the e:\ABC\WindowService_VS2012\wins_Test.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   e:\ABC\WindowService_VS2012\wins_Test.InstallLog.
>
> The Rollback phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed.

Please advice me what my missing step is.

Comment: try running installutil from a command prompt as adminstrator (right-click command-prompt and choose - run as administrator

Answer (score 1):

Enable and check the fusion logs to see what exactly is going wrong. A quick fusion log demo here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Also, ensure that the probing path for your application is properly set in App.config. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx